# Combining 'marker-based' AR with 'marker-less' AR as a fallback

Tags: android-studio, augmented-reality

How can I use 'marker-less' AR as a fallback to 'marker-based' AR mobile app? When the app fails to detect the markers on the camera view, it should use marker-less AR to maintain the illusion until another marker is detected.

of course the result from the marker-less AR can be erroneous or limited. But that would be sufficient for it to be used as a fallback.

I'm currently using Vuforia as my AR SDK in Android studio. But solutions from any SDK for Android studio will be highly appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When losing tracking it is often best to fall back into a "limited mode" using only the rotational information provided by the gyroscope. This way at least the rotation of the camera is accounted for, though no translation.

Markerless tracking with a single camera usually requires the user to perform an initialization step in which the user has to carefully move the camera along a single axis. You probably don't want the user to do this when tracking of the marker is lost. Of course you could always have the markerless tracking running in the background and take over when the marker is lost, though I'm fairly certain current phones don't have the necessary computational power to run two trackers at the same time.